# neo4j stop command timing out, database is inaccessible

Tags: neo4j, restart

This situation is different from those of similar questions. We are having a hard time stopping our neo4j database, it is taking a lot of time to stop, even though we are increasing the timeout to 3600 seconds. The stop command fails with timeout error (meanwhile the database is no longer accessible, although there's still a neo4j process running). No logs are generated other than `Neo4j Server shutdown initiated by request. Stopping...` (checked both neo4j.log and debug.log).

Below are system-related details:

```
neo4j version: 5.6.0
OS: linux Debian11
JDK version: 17 (was installed along with neo4j)
installation type: native ( installed via apt, was run by `neo4j start`)
dataset size: ~1TB
cpus: 64
memory: 720GB
```

memory configuration(in /etc/neo4j/neo4j.conf):

```
server.memory.heap.initial_size=128G
server.memory.heap.max_size=128G
server.memory.pagecache.size=350G
```

current output of `free -h` command:

```
# free -h
               total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           708Gi       503Gi       2.9Gi       0.0Ki       202Gi       200Gi
Swap:             0B          0B          0B
```

This is the output of `NEO4J_SHUTDOWN_TIMEOUT=3600 neo4j stop --verbose` command:

```
neo4j 5.6.0
VM Name: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM
VM Vendor: Debian
VM Version: 17.0.7+7-Debian-1deb11u1
JIT compiler: HotSpot 64-Bit Tiered Compilers
VM Arguments: [-Xmx128m, -Dapp.name=neo4j, -Dapp.pid=2052130, -Dapp.repo=/usr/share/neo4j/repo, -Dapp.home=/usr/share/neo4j, -Dbasedir=/usr/share/neo4j]
Configuration files used (ordered by priority):
/etc/neo4j/neo4j.conf
--------------------
Stopping Neo4j............................................................................................
Please see logs/neo4j.log for details.
org.neo4j.cli.CommandFailedException: Failed to stop
        at org.neo4j.server.startup.Bootloader$Dbms.stop(Bootloader.java:503)
        at org.neo4j.server.startup.StopCommand.execute(StopCommand.java:49)
        at org.neo4j.cli.AbstractCommand.call(AbstractCommand.java:92)
        at org.neo4j.cli.AbstractCommand.call(AbstractCommand.java:37)
        at picocli.CommandLine.executeUserObject(CommandLine.java:2041)
        at picocli.CommandLine.access$1500(CommandLine.java:148)
        at picocli.CommandLine$RunLast.executeUserObjectOfLastSubcommandWithSameParent(CommandLine.java:2461)
        at picocli.CommandLine$RunLast.handle(CommandLine.java:2453)
        at picocli.CommandLine$RunLast.handle(CommandLine.java:2415)
        at picocli.CommandLine$AbstractParseResultHandler.execute(CommandLine.java:2273)
        at picocli.CommandLine$RunLast.execute(CommandLine.java:2417)
        at picocli.CommandLine.execute(CommandLine.java:2170)
        at org.neo4j.server.startup.Neo4jAdminCommand.call(Neo4jAdminCommand.java:123)
        at org.neo4j.server.startup.Neo4jAdminCommand.call(Neo4jAdminCommand.java:42)
        at picocli.CommandLine.executeUserObject(CommandLine.java:2041)
        at picocli.CommandLine.access$1500(CommandLine.java:148)
        at picocli.CommandLine$RunLast.executeUserObjectOfLastSubcommandWithSameParent(CommandLine.java:2461)
        at picocli.CommandLine$RunLast.handle(CommandLine.java:2453)
        at picocli.CommandLine$RunLast.handle(CommandLine.java:2415)
        at picocli.CommandLine$AbstractParseResultHandler.execute(CommandLine.java:2273)
        at picocli.CommandLine$RunLast.execute(CommandLine.java:2417)
        at picocli.CommandLine.execute(CommandLine.java:2170)
        at org.neo4j.server.startup.Neo4jCommand.main(Neo4jCommand.java:41)
        at org.neo4j.server.startup.Neo4jBoot.main(Neo4jBoot.java:30)
```

Any help on this is highly appreciated.